# How to get the REAL gcc (not the one that is hashed to clang) in MacOS?

Tags: osx, gcc, c, linker

I am trying to compile a program that uses the OpenSSL library.  I had a problem where it couldn't find the header files.  I fixed this problem by adding the option `-I /usr/local/opt/openssl/include` to `gcc`.  After this, I had another problem, which is that the linker does not understand some symbol.  This is the error I got:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_MD5", referenced from:
      _main in md5-b35556.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I googled the error, and got a whole lot of results that either only applied to C++, or only applied to programs with multiple modules, etc.  Finally, I found what might be a solution to my problem, which is that `gcc` is hashed to `clang` on MacOS (I am using El Capitain).

So basically, now I need to find the real `gcc` executable, then redirect the `gcc` command to that file with an `alias` command in my `.bashrc` file.  Where can I find this executable in my filesystem, or do I need to install it from the Internet?

Note: I had this same problem when trying to use the ncurses library.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38222/how-do-i-install-gcc-via-homebrew

Comment: This is a sledgehammer to crack a walnut, and (ironically) it won't help anyway.  The right course of action is simply `-lcrypto` and an `-L` for the relevant lib directory.  Sadly, you'll end up switching to GCC and [having the exact same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908158/) because _the compiler was never the problem to begin with_.  Neither GCC nor clang magically include the OpenSSL header file paths or link libraries from places like `/usr/local/opt`.  You have to add the command line options that specify them.

Answer (score 3):

Apple Macos uses clang as it's gcc compiler mainly because of the gcc licensing. You can install GNU gcc [using brew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38222/how-do-i-install-gcc-via-homebrew). No apple program installs GNU gcc but you can do it manualy and configure to use it by default.

Comment: Side note: `gcc` is linked to `clang` to help developers and scripts that assume every system has `gcc`. This causes problems for broken scripts that use `gcc` for C++ code.